# Why are Python issues preceded by `bpo-`?

Tags: python, issue-tracking

I've raised two python issues, but can't work out why the issue numbers are referred to as `bpo-xxxxxx` where `xxxxxx` is the issue number.

What is the etymology for this, or what is `bpo` an acronym for?

Why is it generally written in lowercase?

Comment: Where is this issue  raised? Some context would help.

Comment: @tdelaney: The [Python issue tracker](https://bugs.python.org/).

Comment: bpo-xxxxxx ends up in the commit message in the python source. There are other sources of fixes but this gives a quick visual hint that this bugs.python.org.

Answer (score 10):

The  Python Developer's Guide's [Issue Tracking](https://devguide.python.org/tracker/) page says:

> The issue tracker is also commonly referred to as *bugs.python.org* and *bpo*.